# JAVA deploy first maven project failed

Tags: java, maven

Please tell me what i do wrong.
I download maven project from springboot.io and import to IDE(intelliJ).
Start to deploy I get error

```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project securing-web-initial: Deployment failed:
> repository element was not specified in the POM inside
> distributionManagement element or in
> -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

I read like this [Problem with deploying spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115685/problem-with-deploying-spring-boot-application) and add to POM.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>Internal repo</name>
            <url>E:\!Distrib\repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>example-repo</id>
            <name>Example Repository</name>
            <url>
                E:\!Distrib\repo
            </url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Nothing changed.

Comment: Did the error message change at all?

Comment: No. Simple step can not complete.

Comment: `E:\!Distrib\repo` is not a URL, but I would have expected the error message to complain.

Comment: What should i write to set up local repository/ For example to folder c:\repo.  Local repository as i understand can  be used https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository

Comment: You already have a local repository, that's where `install` puts artifacts, and where artifacts downloaded from other repositories live. You don't need to do anything unless you want to move it from `~/.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 1):

If I use a URL `C:\!Users\tgdavies\testrepo` I get the error message: `Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access C:\!Users\tgdavies\testrepo with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory`

If I use `file:C:\Users\tgdavies\testrepo` deploy succeeds.

But your issue is that you *do not need to run `mvn deploy`*. Read the tutorial you linked to -- it does not suggest running `mvn deploy`. To test your code

> If you use Maven, you can run the application by using `./mvnw spring-boot:run`. Alternatively, you can build the JAR file with `./mvnw clean package` and then run the JAR file, as follows:
> `java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar`

Comment: No It is not help. May be Java not for me. According https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch . This task take  less 15 minutes and very easy.

Comment: Why do you want to run `mvn deploy` at all?

Comment: I wand to downloads example and start learning how work spring boot sec. At the first i would like to run Hello world with auth.

Comment: it is very easy if you follow the steps.. 
try to run the tutorial step by step first. Then add in your own extra steps later.
are you already familiar with git and maven?

Comment: Never use. If I will find manual step by step I will follow it. Thank you.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Import I made correctly. It is very easy. I suggested it need a lot of task after import maven project because Run button was not active. As additional automatically was open maven window with deploy and install items)).
intelliJ did not make configuration for run. As a result run button was not active.